# When/how should a new user flag their own question as not useful?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I recently posted a question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107255/postgresql-hot-standby-changing-password-out-from-under-me. As you can see in the latest edit, I still don't know the cause of my error or what I did to fix it. Based on one of the comments on the question, the situation I thought I had should be impossible.

I don't see any way to salvage a clear and answerable question out of the situation. Is a vote to delete correct? A vote to close? Since I don't have the reputation to vote to close, how do I get the attention of someone who can?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless your question has multiple answers or a single up-voted answer you can just delete it. So if it is truly irredeemable, then just click on that "delete" link.

I know it's says "vote to delete", but your vote is binding and the question will be deleted immediately.

Comment: I found that button and figured it would be a good one to click (even if it turned out not to be right). I hadn't noticed that the post was deleted immediately. Looks like the system handles clueless users like me. :)